# Is there a way to create multiple AWS VPCs and multiple subnets for each VPC using the same terraform script?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc, terraform-cli

Terraform novice here. I would like to create a scaled environment on AWS using terraform cli. My input variables are `N_vpc` (count), `region`, `aws_profile`, `M_subnet_per_vpc`. Is it possible to use `count` and `for_each` meta arguments to write a terraform script that creates N VPCs and M subnets in each of those VPCs within a single terraform custom module?

I tried to use `count` meta argument in the VPC resource block to create `N` VPCs in a given region and then tried to create a subnet resource block with `count = M` and `for_each = vpc[*].id` but realized that `count` and `for_each` meta arguments cannot be used in the same resource block.

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# CREATE THE VPC, and Subnets
# N VPC
# M SUBNETS PER VPC
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_vpc" "customer_vpc" {
  count      = var.vpc_count
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr
  tags = {
    Name = "vpc-${random_id.deployment_id.hex}"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "customer_subnet" {
  count    = var.subnet_count # --> count and for_each cannot be used in the same block
  for_each = aws_vpc.customer_vpc.id
  vpc_id   = each.value
  tags = {
    Name = "subnet-${random_id.deployment_id.hex}-${count.index}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share any code which you had tried, it would be easy to answer with the correct context.

In general, you could use any meta-argument [count or for_each] , preferable and recommended is  for_each for creating multiple resources with one root module call

Comment: I've added the code snippet @ishuar. My issue is creating M x N resource matrix, where N is the number of VPCs and M is the number of subnets per VPC and both VPCs and subnets must be created in the same module

Comment: one VPC to many subnets will be a better approach in my POV, multiple VPCs to multiple subnets can cause mapping, referencing, and dependencies issues in a single module. 

Create a VPC without any count or for_each and then use looping on the subnets only, If you already have a static number for VPCs and Subnets then sure its possible to do in the single module and mapping also but not feasible with dynamic VPC (N) X Subnets (M) 

Offcial AWS VPC module just for reference
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/master/main.tf#L20